# Auto fill forms in several websites using Python

Tags: python, forms, selenium, mechanize

I have 300 landing pages with different html structures. In each website there is a callback form. I have to write a script which can automatically fill the forms as name and email and submit them. I have tried selenium, lettuce, behave and mechanize, but most of them work with certain html structure. What can I do? And what can I use?

Comment: You probably need to narrow your question down to one specific issue you're dealing with. Questions about tools to use aren't really meant for StackOverflow; see [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

It would be more helpful to show some of the actual links.  Without that specific information, I could hazard a guess.  You could try webbot.  Webbot even works web pages which have dynamically changing id and classnames and has more methods and features than selenium or mechanize.

```
from webbot import Browser 
web = Browser()
web.go_to('google.com') 
web.click('Sign in')
web.type('mymail@gmail.com' , into='Email')
web.click('NEXT' , tag='span')
web.type('mypassword' , into='Password' , id='passwordFieldId') # specific selection
web.click('NEXT' , tag='span') # you are logged in ^_^
```